# How to bring an android service into foreground or prevent it from being automatically stopped otherwise, without using intentservice?

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service with graphic elements, that needs to run for a few seconds then stops itself (all while the app itself is in background). But often times the system automatically closes the service due to low RAM.

I am new to android, and all the codes for bringing service in foreground are using IntentServices.

Can only IntentServices be brought to foreground? If yes, how can I prevent my service from closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`startForeground()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int, android.app.Notification)) method of `Service` class. Do note that it requires you to provide a `Notification`.

> I have a service with graphic elements

What exactly does that mean? A `Service` in Android is meant for the exact opposite use case - i.e., when there is no user interaction desired.

Comment: Doesn't FB chat head and the likes use services for user interaction? And use it well?

Comment: @VishweshSingh Hmm I hadn't thought of use cases like FB chat heads.